# How to return value from 2 tables in one linq query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

please consider this table:

```
PK_Id          Number            Year            Month             Value
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1              1                2000              5                 100000
 410            4                2000              6                 10000
 8888           1                2001              5                 100
```

I  `Id=8888` and now I want to **first** select record with `Id=8888` and **second** select previos year of that record*(I mean Id=1)*. How I can do this with linq and one query.

basically we have some queries that first it should find a value from a table (that may be not PK) and find **Corresponding** records in another tables. How I can do this with linq and one reference to database.

thanks

Comment: Select two times, isn't that fine?

Comment: Whats the criteria for this select query, are you passing in a PK_Id to find for the first row, and then how is the second row linked? Year2 = Year1 - 1?  What about month, does number come in to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from a in Record
where a.PK_Id == 8888
from b in Record
where b.Number == a.Number && b.Year == a.Year - 1
select new { Current = a, Previous = b }
```

or

```
Record
.Where(a => a.PK_Id == 888)
.SelectMany(a =>
    Record
    .Where(b => b.Number == a.Number && b.Year == a.Year - 1)
    .Select(b => new { Current = a, Previous = b })
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, then you need to filter the data of one table and join two tables.

You can join the tables and filter your data

```
var query = from c in Table1
            join o in Table2 on c.Col1 equals o.Col2
            where o.Col3 == "x"
            select c;
```

or you can filter your data from one table and then join the tables (result will be the same)

```
var query = from c in Table1.Where(item => item.Col3 == "x")
            join o in Table2 on c.Col1 equals o.Col2
            select c;
```